# flutter charts with json

Tags: sql, json, flutter, dart, pie-chart

I want to make a pie chart or bar chart on flutter using json, I am struggling to find any examples on this. I wanted to know if this is possible?

Or if it is possible to connect a database like MYSQL to a flutter chart

Comment: Check out this link, it has been answered already:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349936/how-to-display-json-data-in-flutter-charts

Comment: I have looked at this and applied it to my own however, I get errors  even though I am using the same date types as in the example

Comment: check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61802919/error-type-string-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listdynamic-in-type-cast) hope it helps.

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809711/how-to-show-json-object-in-piechart-in-flutter